# 0 commission Crypto exchanges?

Tags: united-states, cryptocurrency

I’ve been trying to find a cryptocurrency exchange other than Robinhood (because I don’t trust them) that has no commissions. I would also like it to be possible to *not* to give them my bank account information in order to trade. Instead maybe using a credit card or writing a check and taking a picture of it (Fidelity allows this) would be a better option. I just don’t trust all these exchanges with that information, it drives me crazy when I read a review saying the company stole their money. I also want to know if it’s true that when there’s major price movement with Bitcoin that Coinbase shuts down or runs terribly?

Is there any trustworthy crypto exchange out there that has 0 commissions (or very very little commissions) and that allows a credit card instead of my bank account info?

Thanks

Comment: You know your bank info is written on the checks, right?  And Coinbase didn’t run any worse in the last mass crypto exodus than any of the misc exchanges in Asia.  I’ll warn you against a zero commission exchange because it’s not as though these exchanges have another way of sustaining their business, so if an exchange offers zero commission I’d just assume it’s a scam.

Comment: @quid I might have misheard what my parents gave as acceptable payment methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No **trustworthy** crypto exchange will allow you to trade without providing bank account info (or other verifiable personal information). Regulations *require* them to collect such information about anyone trading crypto on their exchange. Any exchange that allows you to trade without providing this information first is operating outside the regulations and thus is **inherently untrustworthy**.

Furthermore, most exchanges stopped accepting credit cards long ago because of the risk of credit card fraud creates: Crypto transactions are irreversible, so if a user buys crypto with a stolen card or cancels the charge, the exchange can't do anything to get their crypto back if the card payment is reversed.

If you are concerned about leaving your crypto assets in the hands of an exchange where they can be taken away from you, I would suggest exploring options for hardware or software wallets which would enable you to transfer the cryptocurrency out of the exchange and into your full control

Comment: Since it would be silly to use an exchange that allows credit card use, are there any exchanges out there that have 0 commissions?

Comment: As the above question comments suggest, any exchange that offers zero commission will just be making money off you some other way (i.e. with bad exchange rates, or selling your information, or just a scam). If commission fees are that much of a turnoff for you, you may wish to reevaluate your cost-benefit analysis. Is the risk of losing all your money in a crypto crash significantly worse than certainly paying $2.50 per trade?

Comment: depending on the risk, yes. I’m only planning on putting in less than $500, so $2.50 *feels* quite large

Comment: Using the same reason you do (which is by all means logical), I’d assume Coinbase Pro has negatives as it’s commssions are lower than Coinbase. It seems Coinbase Pro has 0.5% fees while Coinbase has a fixed $0.99 fee for transactions less than $10, $1.49 for ones between 10 and 25 dollars, etc... is there a reason for this since they’re both made by the same company?

Comment: Speculating on different fee structures is a much more nuanced affair and I'm not familiar enough with their offerings to say. Perhaps one is aimed at more frequent or professional traders, or has a lower business cost for Coinbase.
Looking into it further, it seems it's possible to make zero-commission trades on Coinbase Pro but it requires a bit of familiarity with trading and limit vs market orders (maker vs taker), etc

Comment: You’re going to the moon anyway, who cares about $2.50…..

Comment: @quid I’m not sure what you mean by that, is that a saying I haven’t heard?